# Prove if ab=1, then a=1 and b=1 or a=-1 and b=-1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Actually, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus {0}$. So, I don't know how to prove if ab=1, then a=1 and b=1 or a=-1 and b=-1

Comment: Consider absolute values of integers.

Comment: Please consider showing an attempt of your own. You should be the one leading the discussion, primarily, on a question that you're stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, we show by induction that 
$$\forall n,m\colon nm\ge n.$$
Indeed, $n\cdot 1=n\ge n$, and if $nm\ge n$ then $n(m+1)=nm+n\ge nm\ge n$.
In particular, $nm=1$ is only possible if $n\le 1$ and $m\le 1$, so ultimately if $n=m=1$.

In $\Bbb Z$, when $ab=1$, then certainly $a,b\ne 0$. If $a<0<b$ or $a>0>b$, then $ab<0$, contradiction. Hence either $a,b\in \Bbb N$ and by the above $a=b=1$. Or $-a,-b\in\Bbb N$ and by the above $-a=-b=1$.